# Chrome extension to Inject form into page that includes rich text textarea

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've got a chrome extension that injects a form into a page with a few basic inputs. HOWEVER, the textarea box loads HTML-structured content with some basic tags (p, b, i, a). I am trying to get the form to interpret the HTML WYSIWYG so that the user does not have to edit the raw HTML itself.

I've tried TinyMCE but it seems like it won't load via a chrome extension on the page.

Comment: Use a `contenteditable` div.

Comment: What do you want to know? You've made a series of statements but forgotten to ask something... :oops: